# XSLT change from elements to attribute format

Tags: xslt

What would be the XSLT to change this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cas:ADDRESS_DETAILS PRIMARY_ADDRESS_INDICATOR="1" ADDRESS_ID="-289495914026885120" ADDRESS_TYPE="45001" ADDRESS_ACTIVE_FROM_DATE="2006-12-23" PERSON_ID="14512823342202880">
   <cas:ADDRESS_ELEMENT VALUE="McMurchy Avenue" TYPE="ADD2" />
   <cas:ADDRESS_ELEMENT VALUE="ON" TYPE="PROV" />
   <cas:ADDRESS_ELEMENT VALUE="CA" TYPE="COUNTRY" />
   <cas:ADDRESS_ELEMENT VALUE="Brampton" TYPE="CITY" />
   <cas:ADDRESS_ELEMENT VALUE="440" TYPE="ADD1" />
</cas:ADDRESS_DETAILS>
```

In to this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cas:ADDRESS_DETAILS PRIMARY_ADDRESS_INDICATOR="1" ADDRESS_ID="-289495914026885120" ADDRESS_TYPE="45001" ADDRESS_ACTIVE_FROM_DATE="2006-12-23" PERSON_ID="14512823342202880" ADD2 ="McMurchy" PROV="ON" COUNTRY="CA" CITY="Brampton" ADD1="440">
</cas:ADDRESS_DETAILS>
```

Comment: It at least partly depends on the context, i.e. if you have several of those `ADDRESS_ELEMENT` elements inside a common parent and want to merge them all together or whether you only want to merge these elements if they are adjacent elements. So you might want to show us more context.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to merge all `ADDRESS_ELEMENT`s inside their parent you can use

```
  <xsl:template match="ADDRESS_ELEMENT[1]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../ADDRESS_ELEMENT" mode="to-attribute"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ADDRESS_ELEMENT[position() > 1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="ADDRESS_ELEMENT" mode="to-attribute">
      <xsl:attribute name="{@TYPE}" select="@VALUE"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation to handle the rest (i.e. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3 (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2q) or the corresponding template in earlier versions)

If you want to transform the child elements into attributes of the parent, as your edit seems to indicate, you can simplify the code. Using a namespace requires some adaption however:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/cas"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="ADDRESS_DETAILS">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, ADDRESS_ELEMENT"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ADDRESS_ELEMENT">
      <xsl:attribute name="{@TYPE}" select="@VALUE"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2q/2

Comment: Hi Martin ... I have clarified the query .. are you able to show me the correct way.

Comment: You have changed the problem and now want the elements transformed to attributes of the parent element. And you have introduced a prefix in `cas:ADDRESS` which has no namespace declaration. But I will make one up.